# Javascript array contain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, contain

```
<div id="image_div">
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="1.jpg" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="2.jpg" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="3.jpg" />
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

On page load, I return a JSON array:

```
{
    "src":["lml7x8nJzI.jpg","TaR7dALIPJ.jpg","TDE2pWgIfa.jpg","tUtuDx1BEf.jpg"],
    "checked":["lml7x8nJzI.jpg","TaR7dALIPJ.jpg","tUtuDx1BEf.jpg"]
}
```

- The `src` contains all the source names of image and `checked` is the checked type of check boxes.
- The `checked` defines which image is checked (every image has a check box).

I need the final HTML like this:

```
<div id="image_div">
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="lml7x8nJzI.jpg" />   
<input type="checkbox" checked />              //this is a checked one
<img src="TaR7dALIPJ.jpg" />    
<input type="checkbox" checked/>                 //this is a checked one
<img src="TDE2pWgIfa.jpg" />
<input type="checkbox" />                    //this is not
<img src="tUtuDx1BEf.jpg" />     
<input type="checkbox" checked />  //this is a checked one
</div>
```

I can use `array contains` in JavaScript, or is there a better way?

My attempt:

```
var initial = "<ul class='gallary'>";
var middle = "";
var end = "</ul>";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < data.src.length; i++)
{
    if (data.checked.contains(data.src[i]))   // How can I do this?
    {
        middle = middle +
            "<li><img src=" +
            "http://localhost/project/user/" +
            "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>" +
            "/pages/" +
            "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>" +
            "/images/gallery/" +
            data.src[i] +
            " />" +
            "<br /><input type='checkbox' value=" +
            data.src[i] +
            " checked/></li>";
    }
    else
    {
        middle = middle +
            "<li><img src=" +
            "http://localhost/project/user/" +
            "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>" +
            "/pages/" +
            "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>" +
            "/images/gallery/" +
            data.src[i] +
            " />" +
            "<br /><input type='checkbox' value=" +
            data.src[i] +
            " /></li>";
    }
}

var complete = initial + middle + end;
$("#project_gallary_layout").html(complete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my complete solution using indexOf

```
$(function(){
  var url = 'http://localhost/project/user/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>/pages/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>/images/gallery/'
    , complete = '<ul class="gallery">'

  data.src.forEach(function(src){
    complete += '<li><img src="' + url + src + '"><input type="checkbox" value="' + src + '"'
    if(data.checked.indexOf(src) > -1){
      complete += ' checked'
    }
    complete += '></li>'
  })

  $("#project_gallary_layout").html(complete);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of Array

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
if (a.indexOf('a') > -1 ) {
    //element is in array
} else {
    //element is not in array
}
```

Note that indexOf method is absent in IE6, but there is an implementation available by Mozilla  on the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#section_5).

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to replace

```
{"src":["lml7x8nJzI.jpg","TaR7dALIPJ.jpg","TDE2pWgIfa.jpg","tUtuDx1BEf.jpg"],
 "checked":["lml7x8nJzI.jpg","TaR7dALIPJ.jpg","tUtuDx1BEf.jpg"]}
```

with

```
{"src":[
    {"src": "lml7x8nJzI.jpg", "checked": true},
    {"src": "TaR7dALIPJ.jpg", "checked": true},
    {"src": "TDE2pWgIfa.jpg", "checked": false},
    {"src": "tUtuDx1BEf.jpg", "checked": true}]
}
```

for instance.

Then you could just write

```
for(i=0;i<data.src.length;i++) {
    var elem = data.src[i];
    var checked = "";
    if (elem.checked)
        checked = "checked";
    middle = middle + 
        "<li><img src=" +
        "http://localhost/project/user/" +
        "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>" +
        "/pages/" +
        "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>" +
        "/images/gallery/" +
        elem.src +
        " />" +
        "<br /><input type='checkbox' value=" +
        elem.src +
        " " + 
        checked +
        "/></li>";
    }
}
```

The only thing different between the two strings you make is the attribute `checked` (which should really be `checked="checked"` if you want to follow standards), so I'd prefer setting a variable `checked` to either an empty string or "checked" depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Nice one,this one i was thinking first...but i am little bit new here,how can i manipulate an array like this ??

Comment: @DileepDil: Do you mean the array in the json object? If the returned object is `data` as in the example you just use `data.src[0].src`, `data.src[0].checked`, `data.src[1].src`, `data.src[1].checked` etc. for accessing the values. You can assign to them like you would any other variable.